# Feature rich type familly

Tags: font-recommendation, typefaces

I've recently taken a liking to using typeface families (IBM Plex, etc.) due to the various conveniences (match well, consistent x-height, caps height, weight, etc.).

However, I'm missing a bunch of the features from more 'feature-rich' typefaces (e.g. Minion Pro). Specifically:

- Serif and Sans typeface, *bonus:* teletype
- Bold, italic, etc. in multiple weights (≥4, ≥6 idealy)
- *Bonus:* slanted variant
- Small caps
- Old-style numerals
- *Bonus:* common maths symbols
- *Bonus:* symbols such as numero, ordinal superscripts...

I've tried doing the obvious (to me) searches on google and have ended up with a mountain of not-quite-what-i'm-looking-for results (i.e. pages on "web-safe fonts", "best fonts of all time", "what to look for in a typeface", etc.)

I'm hoping that the well-versed folks over here may be able to point me in some good directions :)

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE! Have you tried asking on [IBM Plex's gitHub](https://github.com/IBM/plex/issues) if these features would be integrated?

Comment: I have had a look there, and unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be much interest from the designers in features such as [small caps](https://github.com/IBM/plex/issues/157) and [old-style figures](https://github.com/IBM/plex/issues/92) :(

Comment: Google's NOTO family might be suited to what you're looking for. https://www.google.com/get/noto/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find sans/serif pairs of fonts?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/61820/how-do-i-find-sans-serif-pairs-of-fonts)

Answer (score 2):

I have two main recommendations. My top choice, although it only has regular and bold weights, is FF Nexus, which has everything you need with a [sans](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fontfont/nexus-sans/), [serif](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fontfont/nexus-serif/), [slab](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fontfont/nexus-mix/) and [monospaced](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fontfont/nexus-typewriter/) version. Collins [use it for dictionaries](https://www.typotheque.com/articles/microtypography_designing_the_new_collins_dictionaries), and flipping through the character set it seems to have everything you need, and a lot of goodies like numbers in circles and swashes. It really is a typeface where one purchase of the pro releases could last you a career, and it's on Adobe Fonts so you can use it there right now if you have a license. (It looks pricier on MyFonts than it is because for some reason the quoted family price is a purchase of both pro and standard releases–you can buy pro-only and it's less than half the price.) Second choice is Thesis from LucasFonts. [Tons of weights](https://www.lucasfonts.com/fonts/package_details/thesans-e4s/the-sans/normal/the-sans) and it's extraordinarily feature-complete with Vietnamese, Greek and Cyrillic, although it's not the cheapest option.

Comment: It is not the first time one of your answers feeds my reading list! Thanks!